# How to create login for android using wcf service

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have create wcf service methot for login.

I want to perform login action in android client. But when I post my object in JSON format to WCF service, I get a Null object (in Wrapped config) or I get an object which fields are null (in Bare config). Does anyone have a solution for this?

This is my Iservice1

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "login?name={name}&password={password}")]
    string login(string name, string password);
```

and this is my login methode on Service1

```
public string login(string name, string password)
  {        

        ads_dbDataContext db = new lidhaj_dbDataContext();
        var messages = from p in db.tblUNI_WEB_Users
                       where p.Student== name && p.Password== password
                       select p;
        if (messages.Count() > 0)
        {
            return "1";
        }
        else
        {

            return "0";

        }


    }
```

and this is my client side in android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
HttpGet httpget;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;


SessionManager session;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    session=new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtShfrytezuesi);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFjakalimi);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txterrorloginmessage);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Validating user...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

void login(){
    try{

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/Service1.svc/login");


        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("response form wcf : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

           // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Njoftimet_e_studentit.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());          
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

but this is not working.
I get this error on my log cat:

```
Exception : Not Found
```

This is my complete log cat:

```
12-16 16:22:55.854    1152-1152/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-16 16:22:55.924       80-253/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.cmd.cmduniverziteti/.MainActivity} from pid 1152
12-16 16:22:55.964       80-253/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (240x394) to layer 21005
12-16 16:22:56.064    1152-1152/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-16 16:22:56.104    1163-1163/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-16 16:22:56.114    1152-1165/? I/AndroidRuntime﹕ NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-16 16:22:56.164    1152-1156/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms
12-16 16:22:56.164    1152-1158/? D/jdwp﹕ Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
12-16 16:22:56.164    1152-1158/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-16 16:22:56.214       80-206/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.cmd.cmduniverziteti for activity com.cmd.cmduniverziteti/.MainActivity: pid=1163 uid=10040 gids={3003}
12-16 16:22:56.414       80-108/system_process I/WindowManager﹕ createSurface Window{41b1aab8 Starting com.cmd.cmduniverziteti paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-16 16:22:56.854       80-118/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ setKernelCountSet(10040, 1) failed with errno -2
12-16 16:22:59.294       80-222/system_process I/WindowManager﹕ createSurface Window{41a29c00 com.cmd.cmduniverziteti/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-16 16:22:59.604       80-118/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ setKernelCountSet(10005, 0) failed with errno -2
12-16 16:22:59.794    1163-1163/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-16 16:23:00.634    1163-1163/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti W/TextLayoutCache﹕ computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
12-16 16:23:00.722        80-80/system_process W/InputManagerService﹕ Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41965210 (uid=10005 pid=177)
12-16 16:23:00.881       80-108/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.cmd.cmduniverziteti/.MainActivity: +4s857ms
12-16 16:23:09.457    1163-1163/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier﹕ KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
    in android.widget.EditText@4178fcf0
    0: sent at 22117781000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22117781, downTime=22117691, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
12-16 16:23:19.274    1163-1166/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 170K, 3% free 14295K/14599K, paused 11ms+23ms
12-16 16:23:20.484      133-133/com.android.systemui D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 863K, 35% free 15865K/24391K, paused 282ms
12-16 16:23:22.034    1163-1163/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier﹕ KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
    in android.widget.EditText@4178fcf0
    0: sent at 22130473000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22130473, downTime=22130387, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    -- recent events --
    1: sent at 22125272000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=14, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22125272, downTime=22125211, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    2: sent at 22125211000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=14, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22125211, downTime=22125211, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    3: sent at 22123234000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=14, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22123234, downTime=22123139, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    4: sent at 22123139000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=14, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22123139, downTime=22123139, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    5: sent at 22123047000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DEL, scanCode=14, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=22123047, downTime=22122983, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
12-16 16:23:28.524       80-253/system_process I/WindowManager﹕ createSurface Window{41a46ca0 com.cmd.cmduniverziteti/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti.MainActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
12-16 16:23:29.714    1163-1179/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti W/SingleClientConnManager﹕ Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
    Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
12-16 16:23:30.093    1163-1179/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti I/System.out﹕ Exception : Not Found
12-16 16:23:30.113    1163-1179/com.cmd.cmduniverziteti I/System.out﹕ nje error ka ndodhur ne konnektim
12-16 16:23:30.668        80-92/system_process W/InputManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@417ce870
```

Comment: Post the complete log cat

Comment: Not Found - can you connect to the web service ?

Comment: yes i can connect my web service

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: This does not directly answer your question, however it does provide an alternative implementation.

I would recommend using WebAPI rather than WCF, for communication with an Android client.  WebAPI implements RESTful, JSON web services that may be more easily consumed by Android and tend to be simpler to write than WCF.  See http://www.asp.net/web-api to get started.  If you're familiar with ASP.Net MVC, switching to WebAPI should be a breeze.

Comment: WCF also implements REST very easily. Simply add an endpoint using webhttpbinding in the config file.